# Are there any implications to refreshing a filtered data extension used in a current send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-email

Are there any implications to refreshing a filtered data extension used in a current send? For example if an email send to a filtered DE is throttled and will take 24 hours to complete, and the filtered DE gets refreshed before the send completes, what happens in this scenario?

Comment: Hello Luke, i am not sure we have enough information (as you might see on Tom's Answer). Are you referring to a normal send process with just throttling or a journey builder send. These are two extremely different scenarios.

Comment: In this instance I was referring to just a normal user initiated send via Content Builder. I have already ruled out using filtered data extensions with Journey Builder, I haven't read anything good about doing so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Initiated Sends will pull the data right before the send - so if data changes between schedule and send, the changed data will be used.  BUT if the send initiates and is throttled to disperse over time, the data for that send is now a 'hard value' and is saved.

Essentially:

1. If data changes prior to Job being initiated and sent, it uses updated data
2. If data changes after Job began and started sending, but is throttled to send over time, the data that is used is what was there when job began.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Is the journey set to run once, recurring or based on an automation?
If once, there will be no implication if you refresh the filtered data extension as long as you wait for the journey to stop analyzing and injecting contacts into the journey.

Journey Builder uses two types of data associated to subscribers (journey builder data and contact data).  Journey builder data is static once it enters into the journey.  Contact data is dynamic based on changes that occur to data based on automations, etls or other modifications.